# Unable to execute Dell BIOS update in Freedos1.0 for Alienware Aurora R5

Tags: ubuntu, bios

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Alienware Aurora R5 and deleted Windows 10. I tried to do a upgrade of BIOS followed this link

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS#Upgrading_with_a_FreeDOS_USB_drive

But I got this error message after typing the executable file name:

> Start to flash......[Y/N] Y
>
> Decompress ROM file, flash setting ... done
>
> Get related information from Rom image file.
>
> Error: Problem allocating memory

What is the solution to this problem?